# Google custom search engine not showing result from my website

Tags: wordpress, search, search-engine, google-custom-search

I recently created Google Custom Search Engine for my website and attached it on my site. Its working fine when I select

> Search only selected site

under the advance option of Basic tab under setup menu of Google CSE. The problem arises when I select

> Search the entire web but emphasize included site

As I understand from the last option that, it should show result from entire web but give preference to the included website. However, I could not find any result from my website.

I tried by typing in search

> site:xxx.com

and it's showing all results to the specific website but if I place

> site:mywebsite.com

It shows no results.

Can anybody shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1):

Refreshing the page several times fixed it for me, though it's not a perfect solution. I think this is a problem that Google has to fix.